# How to display/show a div after window.location.href in jsquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am getting data from server through ajax actually, so after fetching the data succesfully i am redirecting to same screen/url, and i need to show/display a div after redirecting ? Is it possible in this way in jquery ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: form_data,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status == 'undone') {

            $('#paypal_email_error').html(response.errors.paypal_email);
            $('.er_msg').show();
        }
        if (response.status == 'done') {
            window.location = '/accounts/email/';
            $('.show_this').show();
        }

    }
    });
});
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="alert alert-error hide show_this">
    <li>Saved Email successfully </li>
</div>
```

Comment: which page you have ajax functions & show this class?

Comment: the page which i am redirecting to here is `/accounts/email/`, so it is the page that contains all code, doing some operations in this page and redirecting to same page

Comment: show this class in child page.accessing those elements from unknown page is possible?

Comment: sorry dint get u, can u make it descriptive ?

Comment: Of course you can not execute code after changing the window.location, it is a new page and JS execution stops. You should just show .show_this element on /accounts/email/ page.

Comment: well said @ChrisKoster .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a query string after redirection url. After all that is a new request to server, so all current context can't be kept, you need another way to convey message.

For example

```
window.location = '/accounts/email/?success=true';
```

Then you can handle the necessary part in server. If params "success" exists and true, then render the "show" part html, or just call this script

```
$('.show_this').show();
```

Comment: Actually i had more than two forms in the same page, so if i dint use ajax, the submitting functionality of all forms are collapsing, so ajax is a must in my case according to my fucntionality